# How to do L1 regularization with constraint?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In $L_1$ regularization we minimize the function $||Ax-b||_2+||x||_1$. In this function $A$ is a matrix, $b$ is a vector and $x$ is the vector variable we want to find by minimizing the function. This is useful in many application. I want my variable $x$ to be either $0$ or $1$.This constraint is not convex and I cannot do exhaustive search for $x$ if $b$ is long or higher dimension. Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can look for conditions on which the optimal solution for $x$ is automatically either $0$ or $1$ even if we only require each component $x_i\in[0,1]$. Then the problem is solvable by quadratic programming. Integer constraints are typically difficult if they do matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, $||x||_1$ is simply $\sum x_i$ when $x$ is binary.

$||Ax-b||_2^2 + \sum x_i$ is a quadratic function, so you simply have a binary quadratic program, which typically is solved using branch-and-bound variants (which is brute force enumeration in the worst-case, as the problem is theoretically intractable and has exponential complexity)

Comment: Is  branch-and-bound variants kind of exhaustive search?

Comment: It's the standard way to solve problems which otherwise would be solved using exhaustive search. In the worst case it still has to search the whole space, but in practice it runs much faster (otherwise we would never be able to solve large-scale integer programs, which is done on a routinely basis everywhere in scheduling, planning etc)

Comment: and when I say standard, I mean standard exact way. The alternative strategy is heuristics